# List all disconnected sessions that are running for 4 hrs and log off them

Tags: powershell, citrix, xenapp

I am creating a script on how to list all the disconnected sessions that are running for 4 hrs but the code does not work.

```
Get-XASession | Select ServerName, State, Accountname, Browsername | where {$_.State -eq "Disconnected", $_.Duration -eq "4 hr"}
```

No error message is showing and not results as well.

But when I run:

```
Get-XASession | Select ServerName, State, Accountname, Browsername | where {$_.State -eq "Disconnected"}
```

It is working.

Need some help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying an operator between your two conditions, instead you have a comma.
Change your code to this:

```
Get-XASession | Select ServerName, State, Accountname, Browsername | where {$_.State -eq "Disconnected" -and $_.Duration -eq "4 hr"}
```

You can see this at play with this code:

```
1..10 | Where-Object {$_ -eq 2, $_ -eq 3}
```

vs

```
1..10 | Where-Object {$_ -eq 2 -or $_ -eq 3}
```

I've answered your question directly above. Here's something that you may want to try though, it should (hopefully) return all sessions older than 4 hours old (I don't have access to these cmdlets so it's a best guess)

```
$lowerThreshold = [datetime]::Now.AddHours(-4)
$session = Get-XASession | Select ServerName, State, Accountname, Browsername | where {$_.State -eq "Disconnected" -and $_.LogOnTime -le $lowerThreshold}`
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but still the same, no error and no results as well. I tried to use the last cmdlets that you provided but still the same issue. I'm using powershell version 4.0 and xenapp 6.0 and 6.5 just sharing it in case the version has something to do with it.